# Two fixed effects variables and one random effect? plm in r

Tags: r, panel-data, plm, random-effects, two-way

I believe I have found a way of having three variables (ID, Time and type) as fixed effect using the plm function (where I have previously indexed the ("ID","Time") in pdata.frame):

```
FixedEffects <- plm(Y ~ x1 + X2 + factor(type), 
                  data = GeneralPanel,
                  model = "within",
                  effect = "twoways")
```

I a looking for a way to now do something similar but where ID is random effect and the other two are fixed. Does this work?

```
RandomEffects <- plm(Y ~ x1 + X2 + factor(type), 
                  data = GeneralPanel,
                  model = "random",
                  effect = "individual")
```

I tried this next piece of code and it did not work:

```
RandomEffects <- plm(Y ~ x1 + X2 + factor(type) + factor(Time), 
                  data = GeneralPanel,
                  model = "random",
                  effect = "individual")
```

It seems to make sense but it gave me this error:

```
Error in solve.default(crossprod(ZBeta)) : 
  Lapack routine dgesv: system is exactly singular: U[28,28] = 0
```

If I take out the factor(Time) it doesn't give an error, but I'm not sure it is giving me the answer I want. If I take out the factor(type) (which is not what I want anyways) it also gives me an error:

```
Error in solve.default(crossprod(ZBeta)) : 
  Lapack routine dgesv: system is exactly singular: U[6,6] = 0
```

How can I do two fixed effects variables (Year and type) and one random effects (ID) with plm in R?